# WCF Method Parameter Unqualified

Tags: .net, wcf, soap

I am new to WCF and I am trying to format the XML for the WSDL

I am not getting the same response as I was getting whilst using SOAP and ASMX

```
<XmlSerializerFormat>
<ServiceContract(Namespace:="fromTest")>
<WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.None)>
<ToolboxItem(False)>
Public Interface iTest

    <OperationContract(Action:="", ReplyAction:="Ack")>
    <WebGet(RequestFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Xml, ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Xml)>
    Function Adjust(<XmlElement(Form:=XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)> ByVal message As stkType) As replyFormat
```

I am expecting the XML as viewd in SoapUI to look like this

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:from="FromLws">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <from:Adjust>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <message>
```

But what I am getting is

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:from="FromLws">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <from:Adjust>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <from:message>
```

The XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified looks as though it is being ignored

Comment: The first thing you need to be aware of is that it's not just **XmlSchemaForm** that affects prefixes. **Elementefort** also influences the prefix. **elementFormDefault** is a property of the schema element of an XML schema, and it also has two possible values: qualified and unqualified. It is used to specify whether local elements defined in the schema (i.e., non-global elements) need to use a namespace prefix. So I think you need to confirm if this information is in the schema.